# CMOS Battery. Forgot to put it in

Tags: battery, cmos

Well. I am a complete idiot. I had to replace my keyboard. And the only way to do that was to completely take it apart. While I was at it I was going to replace my CMOS battery. I took it out. Went to get another one and just realized it is still sitting next to me. I noticed my time is about 2 hours out. And my laptop has been on for about an hour. Anything going to happen to my bios or anything that I should be prepared for when I turn this baby off? Or will everything be fine?

From my understanding it only effects the time and date. So there shouldn't be any problem right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything will be fine. All CMOS settings will revert back to factory default. Just put the battery back in, reconfigure your settings in BIOS how you want them and drive on.

Comment: I haven't touched the BIOS on this laptop before, so really everything should be exactly how they were right?

Comment: Correct. You can reconfigure the clock in BIOS if you want, but resetting it through Windows is just as easy.

Comment: Windows 8 seems to do it automatically.